# Increment в MySQL одним запросом

Tags: sql, mysql

Доброй ночи, товарищи! Помогите написать запрос в базу MySQL:

```
SELECT `flag` FROM `tab0` WHERE `id` = `123`
```

далее: к значению ++ и записать туда же

```
INSERT INTO `tab0` (`flag`) VALUE (`мой изменённый флаг`) WHERE `id` = `123`
```

Если по русски: нужно к значению в колонке flag прибавить единицу, где id строки = 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так?

```
update tab0
set flag=flag+1
where 
  id=123;
```

Comment: Да, простите за такой вопрос я совсем забыл про апдейт)